# DocuSign Prefilled Tabs Position

Tags: c#, docusignapi, docusign-sdk

I am attempting to use the pre-fill tools specifically Text on my Template. I drop a prefill Text box where I want the content to appear and give it a Data Label to use later: "TestValue". The Location values are automatically populated based on where I put the box on the template.

[image: prefill-text-properties]

I am using the C# SDK and the following code to set the dynamic value of the Prefill Tabs:

```
        string someValue = "PreFilled Text";
        var prefillTabs = new PrefillTabs()
        {
            TextTabs = new List<Text>()
            {
                new()
                {
                    PageNumber = "1",
                    DocumentId = "1",
                    TabLabel = "TestValue",
                    Value = someValue
                }
            }
        };
        var tabs = new Tabs
        {
            PrefillTabs = prefillTabs
        };
        envelopesApi.CreateDocumentTabs(token.Account.AccountId, envelopeId, "1", tabs);
```

It seems to completely ignore the TabLabel value for the box I added to the Template where I would like the dynamic text to go. It writes the content in the top left corner of the screen:

[image]

The only way I could figure out how to move the text was to add hard coded coordinates:

```
TextTabs = new List<Text>()
{
    new()
    {
        PageNumber = "1",
        DocumentId = "1",
        TabLabel = "TestValue",
        Value = someValue,
        XPosition = "317",
        YPosition = "204"
    }
}
```

Can someone please explain why it is ignoring the position of the Text box as defined on the template?  Is this not possible, or is there an alternative way I can do this?  I really don't want to hard code all the positions in the code but just refer to the TabLabel so when it gets moved around I don't have to recompile.

Documentation:
https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/esign101/concepts/tabs/prefilled-tabs/

Answer (score 0):

First, I'm not sure you need to use pre-filled tabs.
**You can pre-fill regular tabs, which are not pre-fill tabs.**
This is just a confusion with the name, pre-fill tabs are sender tabs. So, if you have a signer that will see this information, you can use regular tabs for this signer, fill their values from API, and make them read-only if you don't want the signer to be able to edit them.

https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/how-to/set-template-tab-values/

Shows how to do that.

The issue in your code is that the tabs are in the template, not in the envelope and that since they're pre-filled, it's a little tricky to update their values using the template model. You may need to use composite templates to do that.

I would seriously advise you to not use pre-fill tabs unless there's a reason beyond the fact that you want the tabs to be pre-filled. **You can pre-fill a tab that is NOT a pre-fill tab** (I know that sounds weird, but that's why I explained it twice).

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply!  I know how to set regular template tabs for a particular role.  I do not want to tie these fields to a particular signer role.  I would like them to available to everyone from the start before any signers are filling out their role specific fields.  I want to use a dynamic values not static.  Is this possible?

Comment: Maybe you can use https://support.docusign.com/s/document-item?language=en_US&rsc_301=&bundleId=gbo1643332197980&topicId=lsv1579552570897.html&_LANG=enus